# WordPress how to display top level category only

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, categories, custom-wordpress-pages

I'm in the process of designing the `category/archives` page for my WordPress site and I've been trying to write out a page title like this:

**Portfolio: Weddings**

I've been using this code which achieves this, however, since the parent and the sub-category are in the same `php` it's annoying trying to style individually with CSS (mainly for mobile devices).

```
<span><?php echo implode( ": ", array_filter( explode( ": ", get_category_parents( $cat, true, ": " ) ) ) ); ?></span>
```

Is there a way I can achieve something more like this?

```
<span class="parent-cat"><?php DISPLAY PARENT NAME  ; ?></span>
<span class="child-cat"><?php printf( esc_html__( '%s', 'myTheme' ), single_cat_title( '', false ) ); ?></span>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you're using `get_category_parents` to retrieve the parent categories. What you asked for is only for two parent categories, but what if there are more than two parent categories?

If you want to get parents separately, you could use `get_ancestors` function which gives you more flexibility. It'll get you all of the parents ids on which you could set up a `foreach` loop and output them separately. If there is only one parent, then that's exactly what you're looking for.

> [`get_ancestors`<sup>Docs</sup>](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_ancestors/)

```php
if (is_category()) {

  $query_obj = get_queried_object();

  $query_obj_parents_ids = get_ancestors($query_obj->term_id, 'category');

  if ($query_obj_parents_ids) {

    foreach ($query_obj_parents_ids as $query_obj_parent_id) { ?>
      <span class="parent-cat-<?php echo  $query_obj_parent_id ?>"><?php printf(esc_html__('%s', 'myTheme'), get_the_category_by_ID($query_obj_parent_id)); ?></span>
<?php

    }
  }
}
```

So if your category has, let's say 3 parents, it will output:

```html
<span class="parent-cat-11">test category parent 03</span>
<span class="parent-cat-8">test category parent 02</span>
<span class="parent-cat-2">test category parent 01</span>
```

The closest parent will get outputed first.

Also note that `parent-cat-{$parent-id}` will be the name of your class which allows you to target your parents with `css` and/or `javascript`.

Note that i've also used `get_the_category_by_ID` function, which will get you the category name based on category ID.

> [`get_the_category_by_ID`<sup>Docs</sup>](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_category_by_id/)

Also if you need the category name for the same page (i.e page title), not parents names, then you could use `echo $query_obj->name;`.

---

This is the example you asked for, in your question:

```php
if (is_category()) {

  $query_obj = get_queried_object();

  $query_obj_parents_ids = get_ancestors($query_obj->term_id, 'category');

  if ($query_obj_parents_ids) {

    foreach ($query_obj_parents_ids as $query_obj_parent_id) {
?>
      <span class="parent-cat"><?php echo get_the_category_by_ID($query_obj_parent_id) ?></span>
<?php 
    } 
  }
?>
      <span class="child-cat"><?php printf(esc_html__('%s', 'myTheme'), $query_obj->name); ?></span>
<?php
}
```

Which will output this:

```html
<span class="parent-cat">Portfolio</span>
<span class="child-cat">Weddings</span>
```

Comment: Thank you for the timely response, sorry I took a while to get back to you. However, this is exactly what I was looking for, thank you! Not only that but thank you for explaining. I had come across the majority of these functions previously, I just wasn't entirely sure how to string them all together (still learning), so you taught me some things which I really appreciate. I guess I should have clarified that I only have 2 levels of categories for my site: PARENT > CHILD. I was also able to turn your code into a function and apply that into the document to keep it more maintained.